# Android - Set text of TextView with Final String Array

Tags: android, textview, settext

I have managed to extract the first letters on a sentence and store that into a variable.

```
String[] result = matches.toString().split("\\s+");
        // The string we'll create

        String abbrev = "";



           // Loop over the results from the string splitting
           for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

               // Grab the first character of this entry
               char c = result[i].charAt(0);

               // If its a number, add the whole number
               if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
                   abbrev += result[i];
               }

               // If its not a number, just append the character
               else{
                   abbrev += c;
               }
           }
```

I then store the values into a Final String Array;

```
           List<String> list = Arrays.asList(abbrev);
          final String[] cs12 = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

I then set the values into a alert dialog as follows:

```
                 builder2.setItems(cs12[0].toString().split(","), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
```

My next task is when the user selects one of the items for it to go into the text view. However it doesn't let me do this.

```
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                 TextView speechText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);            
                speechText.setText(Arrays.toString(cs12));

                //   TextView speechText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);            
                  // speechText.setText(matches.get(item).toString());
```

However for my other parts matches.get works fine but I cant seem to get cs12.get.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cs12[0].toString().split(",")[item]` to show selected item in `TextView`:

```
String[] strArr= cs12[0].toString().split(",");
speechText.setText(strArr[item]);
```

Comment: @BasicCoder: one more suggestion instead of calling `split` again add `String[] strArr= cs12[0].toString().split(",");` line before `builder2.setItems` line and pass `strArr` as first parameter to `setItems` and use same Array instead onClick to get selected item

Comment: I appreciate it (I had to wait 5 minutes)